# Variáveis de sessão em ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Tenho um método em AJAX que me envia um determinado valor, quando assim solicitado, para uma variável de sessão (uma lista de strings neste caso).

**Variável de sessão**

```
private static List<string> ListData {
  get{return (List<string>) Session["ListDataSession"];}
  set {Session["ListDataSession"]=value;}

}
```

**Método AJAX**

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Teste.aspx/UpdateData",
        data: '{name: "' + "newValue"+ '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
        }
    });
```

**Método C#**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static bool UpdateData(string name)
{
    UpdateData.Add(name);
    return true;
}
```

Como tornar esta **variável de sessão única** neste tipo de casos em que preciso de ter declarado uma variável estática para gerir a informação que vem via AJAX?

Esta questão surge porque abrindo duas *tabs* em que a mesma variável é usada não consigo garantir a integridade dos dados.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que assim funcionaria

```
private List<string> ListData 
{
get {return (List<string>) HttpContext.Current.Session["ListDataSession"];}
set {HttpContext.Current.Session["ListDataSession"]=value;}

}
```

No seu método C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static bool UpdateData(string name)
{
  UpdateData.Add(name);
  return true;
}
```

Acho que esse link do SO responde a sua dúvida.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758575/how-can-i-access-session-in-a-webmethod

Nunca é bom utilizar propriedades estáticas nesse caso, porque caso dois usúarios estejam acessando a aplicação ao mesmo tempo eles vão acessar os mesmos dados.